# Waiting for extension User-Agent Switcher for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

So I'm trying to visit http://www.banknote.ws/COLLECTION/countries/ASI/KUW/KUW0024.htm in Google Chrome and none of the images are loading. The status bar just keeps saying "Waiting for extension User-Agent Switcher for Chrome...".

If I visit the site in Firefox it works just fine.

I guess I could uninstall that extension but I sometimes do use it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested if the page works with the extension disabled (not uninstalled)? Uncheck Enabled in the extension's settings for that that extension.

If it does work with it disabled then, either leave it disabled until you need to use it and then toggle it back on or leave it enabled and toggle it off when the page doesn't work with it on.